# jQuery, checking to see if <input> has a value when first loading the page

Tags: jquery

I would like to check if the form's inputs have a value once the page loads for the first time. If so, then add a class.

Here's my code so far,

```
if( $('input').val() ) {
          $(this).addClass("correct");
    }
```

Do I need to be checking for length? Here's the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/SFk3g/ Thank you

Comment: Why not add the right class on the server-side?

Comment: The answer is likely driven by business requirements, e.g. *what qualifies as a valid input value?*

Comment: Do you mean you want to check every input element and add the class just to the ones that contain something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If serverside code isn't an option, you can use `filter`:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return this.value;
}).addClass('correct');
```

A plain selector might also work:

```
$('input[value!=""]').addClass('correct');
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yhwYQ/

```
// Select all input elements, and loop through them.
$('input').each(function(index, item){
    // For each element, check if the val is not equal to an empty string.
    if($(item).val() !== '') {
        $(item).addClass('correct');   
    }
});
```

You can select all input elements, and loop through them, then apply your check. In this case, you have just mentioned to check if they are empty - this allows you to add additional checks as required by your business logic as required.